# Find $x$ so that $\left|\begin{array}{r}1&x&1\\x&1&0\\0&1&x\end{array}\right|=1$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I want to find a certain $x$ that belongs to $\mathbb R$ so that

$$\left|\begin{array}{r}1&x&1\\x&1&0\\0&1&x\end{array}\right|=1$$

This should be easy enough. I apply the Laplace extension on the third row so  I get

$$0-\left|\begin{array}{a}1 & 1\\x&0\end{array}\right|+x\left|\begin{array}{r}1&x\\x &1\end{array}\right|=1$$

So we have

$$-(0-x)+x(1-x^2)=1\implies x+x-x^3=1\implies x^3-2x+1=0$$

I'm kind of stuck because I'm not entirely familiar with solving cubic functions. I don't think there's a way to refactor this. Perhaps I should have found another way to solve this. $x=1$ is definitely a solution, but there's another one that I'm missing. Any hints?

Comment: Guess a value of $x$ that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Notice that $x=1$ is a solution, hence you can reduce the problem to a quadratic equation.

Comment: Thanks. $x=1$ works. Though I'm not sure how to reduce the problem to a quadratic equation. Do I need to replace the variable $x$ with something else to make it easier to find the roots of the equation?

Comment: @Cesare: use long division to factor.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Do I need to divide the equation by $x$ using long division?

Comment: @Cesare: not exactly.

Comment: $x^3-2x+1 = (x-1)(ax^2+bx+c)$ , can you determine $a,b,c$ , say, by comparing coefficients or long division. whichever that is more comfortable. or by substituing some values of $x$.

Answer (score 2):

as said before : $x=1$ is a solution.

You can then reduce you polynomial to: $x^3-2x+1=(x-1)*(x^2+x-1)$

So you can solve the second degree polynomial and get the two other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Polynomial long division:

$\small{(x^3-2x+1)÷(x-1)= x^2 +x-1}$;

$\small{ -(x^3-x^2)}$

$-----$

$\small{x^2-2x +1}$

$\small{ -(x^2-x)}$

$------$

$\small{-x +1}$

$\small{ -(-x+1)}$

$------$

$\small{0}$